# data pattern matching using R

Tags: r, design-patterns, matching

I have just started using R and I have encountered with an obstacle when dealing with my raw data. So this is the problem. I have two data sets A and B with same number of rows (names of the firms) and columns (months). But apparently I have to match the pattern of data locations, (for example. if (i,j) of A is blank,  then I need to erase the entry in data B of (i,j). I need to have same number of cells and same pattern of data allocation on both data sets. I have tried  this double loop , but it doesn't work.

```
  for (i in  1:length.firm)
            for (j in 1:time.)
                  if (CR [i,j] == ",") marketreturnmonthly[i,j] == ","
```

can anyone show me how to solve this problem? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLF1i.png)

Comment: Perhaps `merge` would be a better course?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use `dput()` to show your data. Please edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43424603/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses the "data.table" package:

```
A <- data.table(symbol = c("1990.01","1990.02","1990.03"), A1 = c(4,NA,NA), A2 = c(6,7,NA), A3 = c(NA, 8, NA))
B <- data.table(symbol = c("1990.01","1990.02","1990.03"), A1 = c(1,4,7), A2 = c(2,5,8), A3 = c(3, 6, 9))
vec <- ifelse(as.vector(is.na(A)), NA, unlist(B))
C <- data.table(matrix(vec, 3))
colnames(C) <- c("Symbol", "A1", "A2", "A3")
C
   Symbol  A1 A2 A3
1: 1990.01  1  2 NA
2: 1990.02 NA  5  6
3: 1990.03 NA NA NA
```